# Output from strace to another window

Tags: strace

Lets say I want to discover how [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) works by [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

Is it possible to redirect the output from `strace` to another window?

So I can have two windows, one for pry where I'm making all interaction, and another window of `strace`'s output.

Comment: The easiest way would be sending strace output to a file and use `tail -f` in the other window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strace -p` in one window to trace a command running in another window. The `-p` option accepts one or more process ids, so you could, for example, try

```
strace -p "$(pidof pry)"
```

if you have at least one process which `pidof` recognizes as `pry`. You might need to experiment with `pidof` (if I want to strace a `pudb3` command, I need to use `python3` rather than `pudb3`), and using `pidof` might not be the best approach if there is any ambiguity associated with it (you might have multiple commands which match but only want to `strace` one of them). It might be easier to find the right process is with `ps` and provide the option directly.

This approach is not likely to work well with a short lived process, or in a situation where it's important to see output from early in the lifetime of the process, but for an interactive application whose startup time isn't especially interesting, it might be workable.

One difference with using `strace -p` as opposed to `strace` without `-p` is how interrupts are handled. A process launched by `strace` will have interrupts like <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> passed along to it (and reported by `strace`), but <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in `strace -p` will detach it, and allow the process to continue without tracing (and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> still works in the application if it's in a separate window).

Comment: This is correct +1, although I'd expand it with a small example.  Also, this will work well for REPLs but not that well for programs that run and then exit (you would not be able to catch their PID).

Comment: Agreed. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually it can kinda sorta work, though would require a small wrapper that reveals the pid, waits for `strace` to start or on some other signal then `exec`s the program proper.

Comment: A wrapper seems unlikely to easily fulfill the goal of using separate windows for `strace` and the process whose system calls it reports.

Answer (score 2):

And the wrapper method for short-lived processes or where it is important to see output from early in the lifetime of the process:

```
#!/bin/sh

# the pid could be sent to a file or named pipe the-thing-that-does-
# strace could be watching, though in most cases a human could copy it
echo "PID to strace is $$"

trap : USR2

# block while human copies pid over to strace (or some program acts on
# the above pid being written in that other terminal). Busy loop or
# something instead if this program must not consume input (`sleep`
# complicates the signal handling)
read blocking

# then when strace is up, send this process a USR2 signal. this will
# mean there will be some strace of this script in addition to the
# target, hence the kinda sorta caveat.
exec echo /the/program/of/interest
```

Or, instead simply run `sysdig` in that other terminal window, as `sysdig` can snoop directly on a program by name:

```
sysdig -p '%proc.name %evt.type(%evt.args)' \
    proc.name contains /the/program/of/interest
```